# Is the following language context-free? $L= \{a^nb^m| m\geq2^n\}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

Is $L=\{a^nb^m|m\geq2^n\}$ a context-free language?

Comment: What do you think? Where did you get stuck? Try using the pumping lemma.

Comment: the pumping lemma is not helping here..because we always can pump only the b's..and then any string will remain in L,

Comment: i think L is not context free language, but im stuck at proving it, iv tried to do some intersections between L and some regular languages, but it didn't help

Comment: Try using Ogden's lemma instead.

Comment: In Ogden's lemma there is the same problem as in the pumping lemma, there is always an option to pump only b's.

Comment: @SaryKhourry Please include your attempts in the question. We don't like problem dumps like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be the integer in Ogden's lemma, and consider the word $a^q b^{2^q} \in L$ for $q$ satisfying $2^q > p$, marking its $b$ part. According to the lemma, we can write $a^q b^{2^q} = uxyzv$ where $xz$ contains between one and $p$ letters $b$. Since $uyv \in L$ and $xz$ contains at least one $b$, it follows that it also contains at least one $a$. For $ux^2yz^2v$ to be in $L$, we need $xz$ to contain at least $2^{q+1}-2^q = 2^q$ letters $b$, contradicting our choice of $2^q > p$.

More generally, this works for any language of the form $\{a^nb^m : m \geq f(n)\}$ for any $f(n) = \omega(n)$, or even whenever $\limsup f(n)/n = \infty$.

Comment: many thanks ,you've been very helpful,i really appreciate it